# Has anyone installed the JumpNote Android C2DM demo application on an unrooted Nexus 1?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Is it possible to run the JumpNote demo application for 
Android Cloud to Device Messaging
http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/
on an unrooted Google Nexus1 phone?
Did anyone install and run JumpNote on an unrooted Nexus1?
(JumpNote works with Android 2.0+, it needs Android 2.2 for push-sync, but it can run and be sync-ed manually in Android 2.1)

Comment: is this a software development question or a user question? If you are not a software developer, then your question will be better asked/answered in a different forum.

Comment: mtmurdock, this is a software development question, but
when you wrote your comment,
did you have in mind a better forum than this for my question about 
running the JumpNote C2DM demo application on an unrooted phone?

Comment: For questions on using Android, use ForceClose (www.forceclose.com). If you have questions about developing for Android, this is the place.

Comment: @CommonsWare, but your answer about developing for Android C2DM is not to put any questions here until Android2.2 is ready for general use.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I see that you deleted your "answer".

Comment: @cristina: the answer wasn't doing you any good. In that case, it is better to leave the question unanswered, so that it is more likely to attract an answer that might do you more good. In my experience, an unanswered question is more likely to attract an answer than a question with one answer will attract a second answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, of course, thank you for deleting your answer.
But I suppose you are right, not many people would have tried to use the JumpNote demo app for C2DM, because Android 2.2 is not available yet for general use. 
I put a question about Android C2DM to the forceclose forum you mentioned, they might send me to yet another forum....

Comment: Also, why the concern about root? You shouldn't need root to run the demo :-)

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you very much, but I get parsing error when I try to install the apk file :(

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to run the demo app on pre-2.2 devices (but not pre-2.0 devices). To do so:

1. Enable non-Market install of apps by enabling 'Unknown Sources' in Settings > Applications on your device.
2. Download the latest .apk file in the [downloads section](http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/downloads/list) of the project **from your device's web browser**.
3. Once the download is complete, tap on the downloaded file (in the Downloads list in the phone's web browser) to install the app.

Note that you won't see the automatic synchronization until your Nexus One is updated to Android 2.2. Also note that JumpNote is just a demo, and shouldn't be used to store any important or sensitive data.

Comment: Hi Roman,
Thank you very much, unfortunately I get 
"There is a problem parsing the package" :(

My phone is Nexus One, Android 2.1, ERE27

Comment: Interesting.. can you try scanning the QR code on this page with the Barcode Scanner app? http://code.google.com/p/jumpnote/downloads/detail?name=JumpNoteAndroid-latest.apk

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you, thank you :) I got the Android 2.2 OTA update and the JumpNote demo app is great and fast.